# Does there exist a SQL query that contains a subquery that can't be rewritten without a subquery?

Tags: sql

I am looking for an example of a SQL query that contains a subquery which can't be rewritten without a subquery and do the same thing, if such a thing exists.

Any example will work, or an explanation of why there is no such thing will work too. MySQL, Oracle SQL, doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, very often sub-query can be replaced by a JOIN.

Comment: if you don't like subquery then use joins

Comment: I'm not asking about very often. Can they ALWAYS be replaced with a JOIN?

Comment: i've answered that already, use join if your subquery is not a predicate

Comment: @DrewCottrill: no. Sub-Queries can not _always_ replaced with a join. Especially for queries testing for the existence of rows in a one-to-many (or many-to-many) relationship as the join would yield a different result.

Comment: The answer is yes, they do exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the following query in MySQL can be written in MySQL as a single `select` statement without a subquery

```
select a.*,
       (select b.bid
        from b
        where b.aid = a.aid
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) b
from a;
```